# are the instance variables value the same in Nestjs singleton?

Tags: singleton, nestjs

As the Nestjs uses [singleton provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#provider-scope) pattern, hence shares a single instance of the provider across the entire application for scope Default, how the instance variables are managed? I wonder if the instance variables are the same for each method execution.

That said, would it be state-conflicted for variables which are supposed to be isolated between executions?

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class CatsService {
  private foo: any;

  someMethod() {
    this.foo = 'Initial value';
    // other changes here
    this.foo = 'Final value';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `foo` will be same for all the method calls in the service, given that, the service is singleton scope (there is request and transient scope other than default) and you have not redeclared the `CatsService` in another module .You can import the module that imports & exports `CatsService` and it will still be singleton.

If you want isolated contexts in your services switch to request or transient scopes, which will give you request/transient scoped variables. Disclaimer: The performance will take a hit. I have personally tested the difference and found that at worst, the average HTTP request took 2x logner to complete and the best case was 18% decrease in average request completion. Your Mileage may vary.

The App I tested was a decent mid size prod app with i/o intensive operation than a compute intensive one. All the providers were Request Scoped.